# Is it possible to soft reset to a shiny Yveltal/Xerneas/Zygarde?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I want to gain some rare and valuable shinies, and I looked towards the games mascots, Yveltal, Xerneas, and Zygarde. I know in previous games (like Diamond and Pearl) you could soft reset the game until the game would give you a Shiny in for the legendary. Can you still do this?

Comment: Is the likelihood of getting a shiny (1 in 8124 I think) the same for soft resetting to get a shiny legendary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Gen V (Black/White), legendary Pokemon encountered in-game have absolutely 0% chance of being Shiny. Shiny legendary Pokemon are now only obtainable through events or hacking.

Comment: That's a bummer. Why do they even put Shiny forms in if you can't get them without an event?

Comment: Because it's much easier to leave the shiny palettes in the game rather than having to patch them in later when they release an event.

Comment: Good point, I am still upset though.

Comment: Kyurem can be caught shiny as far as i know. Do you know the reason for this? Wouldn't this possibly apply to Zygarde as well?

Answer (score -1):

Because Gamefreak discourages soft resetting and wants you to only get legendaries nonshiny, or through events that make them shiny, they made it impossible to catch a shiny legendary since Generation V.